# How to retrieve all snapshots related to a AWS EC2 instance using BOTO3 Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am tangled in of the situation: I can retrieve all the snapshots of a volume associated with a *EC2* instance but once the EC2 instance gets deleted so does its associated volume. I have been rubbing my head around the Boto3 documentation and struggling. Below is my working example to list the snapshots associated with the Volume.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
volume_id = "something"
list_of_snapshots = []
vol = ec2.Volume(id=volume_id)
snapshots = vol.snapshots.all()
    try:
        for snapshot in snapshots:
            if snapshot:
                list_of_snapshots.append(snapshot.id)
        return list_of_snapshots[0]
    except:
        return None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to tag the volumes when they are initially created. The tags will stay with the volumes even when the instance is deleted.

Amazon EC2 can now propagate tags to volumes on launch.

See: [Tag EC2 Instances & EBS Volumes on Creation | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-tag-ec2-instances-ebs-volumes-on-creation/)

Comment: This is exactly what I used but doesn’t it make sense that there should be instance-id somewhere :/. It can actually be useful.

Answer (score 1):

As @John Rotenstein suggested,

The possible solution right now is to add the VolumeID inside the tags while creating the snapshots, so the code turns out to be something like this:

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
volume_id= "something"
list_of_snapshots = []
    snapshots = ec2.describe_snapshots(Filters=[{'Name':'tag:volume_id', 'Values': [volume_id]}])['Snapshots']
    try:
        for snapshot in snapshots:
            if snapshot:
                list_of_snapshots.append(snapshot['SnapshotId'])
        return list_of_snapshots
    except:
        return None
```